# Can current flow through a relay's NO channel when it's not energized?

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

Can current flow through a relay's NO channel when it's not energized?

I'm an electronics newbie and I built a circuit where a relay is operated by a Raspberry Pi Zero W. See circuit image. The relay used is a SRU-06VDC-SD-C. It's rated for 6v but I hear it click open and closed using the 5vdc from the Pi.

I would use this to turn my heating on and off at home, the circuit that switches heating on and off is a 110V DC line coming from my heating installation (my AC voltage is 220V). When this circuit is closed, the heating is turned on. This line is wired to the NO contact.

It worked fine for weeks when testing but when actually wired up to the heating it worked for about a week but now the heating is always on, even when I explicitely do not energize the relay. The heating is even turned on when the pi is switched off. When I measure with a multimeter, the meter claims the circuit is not closed. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance!

(updated after advice from Transistor)

[image: Raspberry relay wiring]

[image]

Comment: My guess is that it couldn't take the load and has failed, stuck closed. If you link to the datasheet we can have a look at its DC ratings.

Comment: http://www.datasheet.fr/datasheet/958849/SRU-06VDC-S-D-C-pdf.html

Comment: That link is to a web page - not a datasheet. It looks like a dodgy site so I'm not going to click anything on it.

Comment: Added image of relay

Comment: What is the inrush current of the heating system? and something sounds wrong about a 110V DC line....

Comment: Anyone know why that thing lists two different DC ratings?

Comment: Trevor, to my knowledge the dc line doesn't actually turn the heating on or off, it tells the system to start circulating hot water to the radiators. Or would something like that still generate inrush current?

Comment: @YdobonAmok without a system wiring diagram, nobody on here can ever be sure.

Comment: does the heater stop when you disconnect the relay? there may be an outside cause.

Comment: @trevor:  I think contact ratings on switches and relays (and many other electrical things) are often determined by  Electrical Code requirements - US/Canada code requirements may be different than European ones, and the components must show both ratings to be acceptable under both codes.

Comment: @jsotola do you mean does the heating keep running when I disconnect that line from my circuit? No, it switches off. If I replace my relay setup with a flip switch for example or connect the original thermostat it works as expected.

Comment: yes, just wanted to make sure that the problem is not someplace else

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but to help you with your terminology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjNsZM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A single-pole, single-throw (SPST) relay.*

- The relay is drawn in its unpowered or de-energised state.
- The common pole wile therefore be connected to the N.C. contact.
- On energisation of the coil the contact will change position and the common pole will then be connected to the N.O. contact.

> Can current flow through a relay's NC channel when it's open (= relay unpowered)?

"Open" in the context of relays means that there is a gap between the contacts so current will not flow. However, you are trying to describe the relay unpowered in which case the N.C. contact will be *closed* and current will flow.

> It worked fine for weeks when testing and when actually wired up to the heating it worked for about a week but now the heating is always on, even when I explicitely close the relay.

I think you mean "when I explicitly *energise* the relay".

If the heating is staying on then the contact is probably welded.

> It's even on when the pi is switched off.

You should expect this if you used the N.C. contact.

> When I measure with a multimeter, the meter claims it's closed.

If you measure the N.C. contact with the relay de-energised then this is the expected result.

> Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

It could be one of a number of things:

- You have used an AC-rated relay on a DC supply.
- You have used the relay to switch a voltage higher than the contact ratings.
- You have provided no snubber across the load to protect the contacts.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I've updated my question to make it more clear...